# List Comprehension in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of tuples:

```
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

and another list, no tuples:

```
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

How would I use list comprehension to multiply only the first value of each tuple in `a` by each respective value in `b`? That is, `[a[0][0] * b[0], a[1][0] * b[1], a[2][0] * b[2]]`
(Should equal `[1, 6, 12]`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
... b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [x[0]*y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[1, 6, 12]
```

The `zip` function is the key.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, you can use
`[a[0]*b for a,b in zip(a,b)]`

The `zip` function creates a list of tuples. The list is as long as the shortest list of arguments to `zip`, and the `i`th element of each tuple comes from the `i`th argument of `zip`.

```
>>> c = [1, 2, 3]
>>> d = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zip(c,d)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

For giant lists you better use `izip` from `itertools` as you don't need to create a new list before iterating over it: http://pymotw.com/2/itertools/#producing-new-values. A huge advantage of this methodology is that you are not limited to sequences. You can use generators as well.

```
import itertools as it

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]

for e in it.izip(a,b):
    print e
```

This prints the tuples:

```
(1, 6)
(2, 7)
(3, 8)
(4, 9)
(5, 10)
```